# Where can I download the source of "appframework.jar" that comes with NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdesktop

I have just started to try NetBeans. I created a new Java Desktop Application project, and it automatically added the JDesktop "appframework-1.0.3.jar" library. However, whenever I try to view its source, the command fails. I tried searching for it online, but I couldn't find it. So where can I download the source code for the "Swing Application Framework" (appframework.jar and swing-worker.jar)?

Answer (score 2):

http://java.net/projects/appframework/sources/svn/show/trunk/AppFramework

the link and the source is too old and hard to be found,luckly i used 30 min find it in :
https://java.net/projects/appframework/sources/svn/show/trunk/www/downloads?rev=151

you can see the "source","jar","doc" of appframework-1.0.3.jar at the ending.

Comment: you might consider BSAF (sorry, don't have the link handy) - it's the improved successor and still maintained

Answer (score 0):

If you came to this question, because you couldn't find "Swing Application Framework" (appframework.jar) using `Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins` My Answer may help you.

First If you just need appframework.jar please get it from the below link.
If you already click the links in other answers you can **Swing Application Framework** has migrated from java.net and hard to find where it is migrated

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.appframework/appframework/1.03

If you just need Netbeans for Swing Application developments, I suggest you use Netbeans 8.0.2 version. As I experienced Latest version does not have the exact IDE which uses in Video Tutorials, Other versions may not properly work with Swing. As per my experience below version will serve you right when it comes to Java Swing Application developments

https://netbeans.org/downloads/old/8.0.2/